# How do I restore a specific folder from an encrypted backup?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, deja-dup

I was wondering how to restore from an encrypted backup but only restore the Videos directory in the backup? The backup is stored on Ubuntu One and I'm using 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your Home directory in Files
2. Right click on the Videos directory
3. Select "Revert to Previous Version…"

Alternatively, if your Videos folder doesn't even exist anymore:

1. Open your Home directory in Files
2. Right click on the background white space
3. Select "Restore Missing Files…"